# Add Website to existing Azure Mobile App (App Service)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing Azure App Service Mobile App. It works fine for iOS and Android clients (and external websites). My understanding is that all App Service options are essentially the same product with different default templates applied, so I'd like to add some web pages of my own to this Mobile App.

I created a test/sample Web App, and in the App Service Editor, there appeared to be only a single file in the `wwwroot` folder: `hostingstart.html`. (Interestingly, there wasn't even a `web.config`. Why is that?)

On my Node.js Mobile App, there is, of course, a large folder structure, which looks like this (some items left out):

- api (folder)
- node_modules (folder)
- tables (folder)
- typings (folder)
- app.js
- iisnode.yml
- package.json
- web.config

I tried adding an `index.html` to this root (`wwwroot`) folder, but then navigating to `http://{service name}.azurewebsites.net/index.html` just gave me the same "this service has been created" page as usual.

So, then I went into my `app.js` file and changed this:

```
var mobile = azureMobileApps({
    // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: true
});
```

to this:

```
var mobile = azureMobileApps({
    // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: false
});
```

After that, the following errors appear:

- Navigating to `{service name}.azurewebsites.net` returns:

  - Cannot GET /
- Navigating to `{service name}.azurewebsites.net/index.html` returns:

  - Cannot GET /index.html

When I encounter an error like this for one of my API methods, I check the settings in the `{api method}.json` file. I don't think that's the answer here.

I am guessing that there is some kind of switch in a file somewhere that allows for direct `*.html` requests to be served. I have the following entry in my `web.config` file:

```
<!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
<rule name="StaticContent">
  <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
</rule>

<!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
<rule name="DynamicContent">
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
</rule>
```

I would assume that I need to change something in here to allow the access, but what?

Comment: Hi @mbm29414, any update yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Interestingly, there wasn't even a `web.config`. Why is that?

Per my experience, if `app.js`/`server.js`/`index.js` is contained in `wwwroot` folder, then Azure App Services will think it is a node.js app and generate the web.config automatically.

> I would assume that I need to change something in here to allow the
>   access, but what?

I don't think you need to change something in here. According to the following lines in web.config. You may want to consider that put your static file (e.g. html, js, css and so on) in the `/public` folder under the `wwwroot`.

```
<!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
<rule name="StaticContent">
  <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
</rule>
```

The following are my tested screenshots.
[image]
[image]

You can also do the same thing with the code below through Express,

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Actually, The `Azure Mobile Apps` Node.js SDK is an `express` middleware package which makes it easy to create a backend for your mobile application and get it running on Azure. The middleware handles particular routes such as `/tables` and `/api`. 
Meanwhile, you are able to mount any other middleware or routes you want onto your express app as well, leaving you free to use any prescribed "best practice" you see fit.

Any further concern, please free feel to let me know.